# Can't connect by filezilla or Putty. sshd. Digitalocean

Tags: linux, centos-7, sshd

I tried to connect by filezilla but I got an error "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)". There I set port 2212, user login. In setting of SFTP I added authorized_keys file which I created by puttygen. The same problem also when I connect by putty. There are I enter only login and get "Server refused our key" and "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)". How can I fix that?

Comment: On DO you can access your machine via a virtual console from your account management pages. Where was the `authorized_keys` file put on the host? In `/root/.ssh` if you login as root, and in `/home/user/.ssh` if you login as `user`? Are these directories and files readable/writable only by their owner (they should be so).

Comment: I have generated authorized_keys by putty, how can I save on the server in folder /root/.ssh? if i open file authorized_keys in folder /root/.ssh by nano and paste copied public code it will be recorded very badly

Comment: How badly? See [here](https://devops.ionos.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/#copy-public-key-to-server) for instructions?